# Calculating Zonal Stacks on imagery with missing pixels

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, rasterstats

I'm trying to calculate zonal statistics on some imagery that has a bunch of pixels that come out as 0s. This is affecting the mean value for the area, or at least seems to be.

I'm using the rasterstats library. Is there some flag to ignore a certain value?

Comment: You've provided very little information about what you've tried (i.e. post your code if you want specific answers). Can you not just use numpy indexing to set the zeros to nans? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778299/replace-the-zeros-in-a-numpy-integer-array-with-nan I am not familiar with rasterstats, but I assume it treats nan's as invisible.

Answer (score 1):

The function help of [`zonal_stats`](http://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/rasterstats.html?highlight=zonal_stats#rasterstats.zonal_stats) links to [`gen_zonal_stats`](http://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/rasterstats.html?highlight=zonal_stats#rasterstats.gen_zonal_stats) since all the parameters you pass to `raster_stats` are passed to `gen_zonal_stats`. 
I think the parameter you are looking for is `nodata`. The help for this parameter says: *If raster is a GDAL source, this value overrides any NODATA value specified in the file’s metadata. If None, the file’s metadata’s NODATA value (if any) will be used. defaults to None.*